# How to update mysql database, with a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To all experts who is going to read this question, It is a basic problem that cost me more than hours to me,

I want to update previously entered row. As it can be seen in the code, I want to update Improvement column. Also I want to do that with the help of the last user id, which is a auto increment primary key entry. However with the code I wrote down here nothing changes in my Mysql database.

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users 
SET Improvement='".$improvement."'
WHERE ORDER BY User_id DESC LIMIT 1 
";  

mysql_query($sql, $accounts);
```

And as you can see this is my table in mysql,

```
users   CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `Username` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Age` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Education` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Department` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Favourite` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Preference` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Lpreference` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Level` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Question` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Improvement` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `User_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

I believe I cannot update Improvement column because of the syntax. In my page no error occurs, and nothing happens even though $improvement not equal to 0. I echo the $improvement variable it is not equal to 0. But noting changes in my database.

I am desperate for an answer, If it works I will select it as best answer for other people who is facing the same problem.

Comment: Hope you are checking the updates in the row having the largest User_id. isn't it?

Comment: yes, As I said I want to update the largest User_Id which means the lastest user that entered database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET Improvement='".$improvement."' ORDER BY User_id DESC LIMIT 1";  

mysql_query($sql, $accounts);
```

Comment: @SyedQarib what is the problem?

Comment: @SyedQarib `Also I want to do that with the help of the last user id`

Comment: @RonnieJamesDio try with `mysql_query($sql, $accounts) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE ORDER BY User_id DESC LIMIT 1` this is wrong in your update query.

use update query like this

```
 $sql = "UPDATE users SET Improvement='".$improvement."' WHERE   User_id = (SELECT max(User_id) FROM users)";
```

Read manual [update query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) from here

Comment: where User_Id= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table)

Comment: $sql = "
UPDATE users 
SET Improvement='".$improvement."'
WHERE User_id= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table)
";   

also didnt worked

Comment: @saty: Update your answer .. with the correct query which should be used in this case

Comment: I got an You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @RonnieJamesDio tell me have this query is working for u or not

Comment: didnt worked, but thank bro anyways, you are a epic guy, I found my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to update the row with the highest `User_id`.  You can do so with a subquery:

```
UPDATE  users 
SET     Improvement = 'GIGANORMOUS'
WHERE   User_id =
        (
        SELECT  max(User_id)
        FROM    users
        )
```

Note that if someone else inserts a row, the latest user will have changed.  It might be better to store the newly created user id for later reference.  Retrieving the `auto_increment` column of a newly inserted row can be done with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

//find the maximum id

```
$sql1 = "Select max(user_id) FROM users";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

$maxid = $row1['user_id'];
```

//do your update like this

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE users SET Improvement='$improvement' WHERE   User_id = '$maxid'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

The above code should work, please ask if the answer is not clear. i would also recommend you start using mysqli